# configure automatic domain join and computer naming

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

***Configure automatic domain join, automatic computer naming, and place new computer accounts in the appropriate organizational unit (OU).***
***Receive a Deploy request from the reference computer and deploy the install image using PXE and network installation.***
this is what I have to do after I configured the active directory and create the users and peppered the WPS server in windows server 2016 but I have no idea what is this or how to do it any think for help please.

Comment: Please check [this](https://www.dtonias.com/windows-server-2016-join-domain/) for domain join

Comment: Also check [this script](http://powershellblogger.com/2015/10/join-computer-to-domain-with-desired-computer-name-and-ou/) , [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/70fae683-e690-4f76-b6f4-ade06b58b9d2/adding-machine-to-correct-ou-during-auto-join-domain) and [series blog](https://johnkeen.tech/windows-server-2016-013-windows-deployment-services/)

Answer (score 0):

•   You can achieve the three things, i.e., joining the computer to domain, placing it in an OU and renaming the computer system through a single script but the other two tasks as stated by you, i.e., receive a deploy request from the reference computer and deploy the install image using PXE and network installation should be done afterwards. For the other two tasks, you can configure a Windows Deployment Services server and deploy an image to be deployed to the respective networks, while also enabling PXE in it and the DHCP server scope also.

•   Please find the below script to join the computer to a particular OU and rename it thereafter. Create a ‘.csv’ file containing the current names of the computers to be joined to the domain and renamed. Then run the below script on each computer individually: -

```
 ‘ Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force ’ --> After running this cmd locally on each computer, run the below script from a domain controller as it will connect remotely through powershell to each computer and join it to domain

  ‘ Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $inputFilePath = <Path of the csv file>
    $computers = Get-Content -Path $inputFilePath
    $domain = <domainname>
    $credentials = Get-credential -username <domain admin username> -password <password>
    foreach ($computer in $computers)
   {
      $ScriptBlock = {Param($computer)
       Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -ComputerName $computer -newname <NewComputerName> -OUPath “OU=testOU,DC=domain,DC=Domain,DC=com”-Credential $credentials -Restart -Force
      }
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $computer
Remove-PSSession -Session $session           
  } ’
```

•   For deploying an image through WDS after domain joining through PXE, refer the following link: -

https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=3089351&seqNum=4